# Form API: Populate tableselect options with AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I want to add a series of sections to the node create/edit form I have for a custom content type. They all work in a similar fashion, in that I pull data from another database and display it for the user to further modify. I will either use a tableselect with checkboxes, or a tableselect with a taxonomy select field (which I will have to research how to do).

The user should have the option to reimport the data if it has been changed on the database by hitting a button that has an AJAX callback attached to it. That's where my problem comes in. I am having a problem with getting the tableselect options to repopulate after import. It seems like the data is being pulled correctly. But the tableselect doesn't repopulate after import, so I assume there is either something wrong with how I have written my submit buttons or the AJAX callback. I can't figure out what exactly is wrong though. How does one handle something like this, especially when one needs multiple AJAX submits?

In the pastebin below I have my entire form, which right now has 2 tableselects and corresponding AJAX callbacks. I need to have 4 in the end. And I have only included the callback function for one of them since they are exactly the same, except for what they query in the DB.

Pastebin, because the code is too damn long: http://pastebin.com/csetteZp